# Disabling SSL 3 on 64bit Chrome for Windows

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, tls

I see lots of different places with the same response for disabling SSL3 on chrome (adding `--ssl-version-min=tls1` to the end of the execution of chrome.exe). But apparently this isn't working for my 64bit version of Chrome (version 40.0.2188.2 dev-m (64-bit)). Anyone have any ideas?

Also note that this is working just fine on 32 bit version on other systems.

Comment: This isn't a POODLE question, it's a client software settings questions and not a good fit for this site.

Comment: @Ramhound please provide what question this duplicates.

Comment: @Ramhound I already saw that and many others like it on this and other sites. You did not read my question carefully. This is specific to the 64 bit version of chrome for windows where the suggested work around doesn't work

Comment: Rootberg, are you saying the fixes suggested at the link do not work in 64-bit versions of Chrome?

Comment: @music2myear correct. 64 bit version for Windows. I can't believe I am the only one that noticed this. Anyway, the solution was simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself... I was looking at an unrelated Chromium issue on the Chromium project page at Google, and happened to see someone telling a user to replace the `--` in the command line flag with a `/`.

So I decided to try this out for my situation and it worked.

SO... For 64 bit Chrome on Windows you need the target to look like this:

```
"[program path]\chrome.exe" /ssl-version-min=tls1
```

Comment: FWIW on my Win 7 x64 box (with Chrome v38.0.2125.104 m) the `--ssl....` and `/ssl....` flag formats appear to work equally well (I opted to use the -- one). Not sure why v40 would be different (unless the Chrome process hadn't fully exited yet before your first attempt).

Comment: No. this is a 64bit chrome only. Not just 64 bit Windows. The normal download for chrome is 32 bit. I understand the confusion :) And I also had no problem with v38.0.2125.104 m

Comment: Ah! So you mean this worked with 64-bit Chrome v38? Weird that only the 64-bit version of v40 has this peculiarity.

Comment: @MartyMacGyver Almost... 32 bit version of Chrome v38 on an a 64bit windows worked fine. Unfortunately, I don't have a 64bit version of chrome that is v38 to test, and I also don't have a 32bit version of Chrome v40 dev to test. I forgot to check if the Mac is 32bit or 64bit chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The fix has been tested, I have it on all the workstations here and did in fact run into one that was not working. It was simply because the Google Chrome process was still running even after closing all browser windows.

After killing the process and then testing it again, the SSL3 checker https://zmap.io/sslv3/ showed it was good to go.

So: 
Make sure that ALL instances of Google Chrome are closed and that there is no rogue processes in Task Manager.

After that, follow the directions as stated to add the `--ssl-version-min=tls1`

Then, if you want to be really consistent, you can also restart the computer or simply log the user off and then back on.

Go to https://zmap.io/sslv3/ or https://www.poodletest.com/ and see if it gives you the green light.

That should do the trick. If you are still having issues I wouldn't blame yourself. I would blame there being something wrong with that workstation.

Comment: Nope. I stopped all google processes prior to apply this. I even rebooted. It doesn't work. Thats why I think it is a chrome 64 bit windows thing. It did work just fine on my Mac version though.

Comment: Yea I can agree with that then, that's just what I experienced. every workstation is different :).